# Python - array copying/assign, unexpected '=array[:]' behaviour for numpy

Tags: python, arrays, list, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I was reading up on copying arrays (&list) by reference or value. However, I ran into an issue here..  To show my problem, I made three examples, each with an assignment and a change.

*First Example:* By default, it is copied by reference.
Thus, the change effekts a and ArrayA, both having the same address. OK

*Second Example:* Since the right hand side is evaluated first, the *1 doesn't change its value, but leads to a copying by value. (I Think this could be done few other ways as well, like using copy() and ..)
Thus, the change does only effect c, having different address than ArrayC.  OK

*Third Example:*
Here I add *[:]* to the array, thus copying the array(=by value), as far as I understand. It can be confirmed, by the different addresses of e and ArrayE. However, the change does not only effect e, but also ArrayE. For me, that´s pretty much unexpected, since it even showed me different addresses before. WHY?

Thanks ahead =)

```py
import numpy as np
# Example 1, by reference
ArrayA = np.array([5,2,3,5,4])
ArrayB = np.array(  [1,2,3,4])

a = ArrayA
a[1:] += ArrayB

print("{}:\t{},\tid: {}".format("ArrayA",ArrayA, id(ArrayA) ))
print("{}:\t  {},\tid: {}".format("ArrayB",ArrayB, id(ArrayB) ))
print("{}:\t{},\tid: {}".format("a",a, id(a) ))

ArrayC = np.array([5,2,3,5,4])
ArrayD = np.array(  [1,2,3,4])


# Example 2, by value
c = ArrayC*1
c[1:] += ArrayD

print()
print("{}:\t{},\tid: {}".format("ArrayC",ArrayC, id(ArrayC) ))
print("{}:\t  {},\tid: {}".format("ArrayD",ArrayD, id(ArrayD) ))
print("{}:\t{},\tid: {}".format("c",c, id(c) ))

# Example 3, by reference/value?!?!
ArrayE = np.array([5,2,3,5,4])
ArrayF = np.array(  [1,2,3,4])

e = ArrayE[:]
e[1:] += ArrayF

print()
print("{}:\t{},\tid: {}".format("ArrayE",ArrayE, id(ArrayE) ))
print("{}:\t  {},\tid: {}".format("ArrayF",ArrayF, id(ArrayF) ))
print("{}:\t{},\tid: {}".format("e",e, id(e) ))
```

```py
ArrayA: [5 3 5 8 8],    id: 2450575020480
ArrayB:   [1 2 3 4],    id: 2450575021680
a:      [5 3 5 8 8],    id: 2450575020480

ArrayC: [5 2 3 5 4],    id: 2450575021280
ArrayD:   [1 2 3 4],    id: 2450575022080
c:      [5 3 5 8 8],    id: 2450575022240

ArrayE: [5 3 5 8 8],    id: 2450575022640
ArrayF:   [1 2 3 4],    id: 2450575022000
e:      [5 3 5 8 8],    id: 2450575022880
```

Comment: "Copy by reference" isn't a thing. You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, then reframe your question.

Comment: it isn't a "copy by reference", it's *not a copy at all*. Note, this has **nothing** to do with pass-by-reference and pass-by-value, which are *evaluation strategies*, i.e. the semantics of how/when arguments to functions are evaluated. Note, Python uses *neither call by value nor call by reference*.

Comment: when you slice a `numpy.ndarray` object, it creates a new *array object* that is a *view* of the underlying buffer in the array that was sliced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** - see @juanpa.arrivillaga's comments below.

In all of your examples, *values* of the `ndarrays` are
`numpy.int32` objects, which are **mutable**.
So from your 3rd example, both `e` and `ArrayE` point to the same `numpy.int32` objects.
That's why the changes are reflected on both.
You can verify that by checking their ids.

```py
print(id(e[0]) == id(ArrayE[0]))
```

Comment: So am I right with this:
So using [:] yields a different array, as seen by the different address the way I did it `id(e)`. But the fields of the new array stay the same, as your matching `id(e[0]))` shows?

Comment: @Wuhuu2 Correct. If you use regular python lists instead of numpy arrays, the values will be of int type, which is immutable. So the changes on one list won't modify the other.

Comment: No, the values in the array and their mutability are irrelevant. Slicing a list in python creates a *new list object*, using shallow-copy semantics. A slice of a `numpy.ndarray` creates a new array object that is a *view* of the underlying primitive buffer.

Comment: Note also, the array doesn't actually contain `numpy.int32` objects. `numpy.ndarray` objects with numerical/structured dtypes are essentially object-oriented wrappers over primitive C-like arrays. `numpy.int32` and the various dtypes actually only exist emphemerally when you access a value in an array to be brought into the interpreter level, sort of like auto-boxing in Java.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That makes more sense. Thanks!